# Where should we put the authorization code? FormRequest, Policies, Controller, Middleware...?

Tags: laravel, authorization

Where should the authorization code in Laravel? We have a lot of options and a lot of plugins to manage this situation but and I'm not really sure where I should put all logic. Let's see:

I know that there are a lot of possibilities with a correct result but I want to know which is the optimal solution for you or know your techniques in this situations.

Imagine we have a help desk application done in vuejs and Laravel as API, so we have users, groups, roles, permissions. And maybe a user will only able to see its tickets.

1. Should we do a TicketPolicy with view, update, create methods? Maybe should we use repositories? Maybe a is_user_allowed method in Ticket's model?
2. Should we use middleware in routes files and do something like Route::get('tickets/{ticket}', 'TicketsController@show')->middleware('can:show')? Or should we call $this->authorize($ticket) in show, edit, update and store methods of the controller?
3. Or maybe should we use FormRequest@authorize method and then use something like $user->authorize('show', $ticket)?
4. What if we want groups or roles? Should we use some plugin like Entrust and/or policies?

What do you think, what do you do?

Comment: all of them are good tbh, it deppends on what you need exactly

Answer (score 0):

Best place I found to put classes that group specific logic that do not fit in standard MVC pattern is completely new folder for Laravel. I name mine Services, probably because I read it somewhere. One of the great things in Laravel (and probably other modern frameworks) is flexibility, you can just pop a folder, add a new namespace and have it contain whatever you need.

As for your example, I would implement a class App\Services\Permissions that would contain all necessary logic for accessing different resources in your application. Then call it's methods wherever you need them, be it Requests, Middlewares or Eloquent Models.